# Expanding Libre Office with Python

Tags: python, libreoffice

I'd like to expand LibreOffice with my own Python scripts.

I want to right-click on a word and run a Python script that would send its output to a different window (not change the doc I am working at). For example, I would click on an author name, and the script would search in a local DB for further information about him. Or I'd run a script and it would output some encyclopedia result.

How do I expand LibreOffice?

Comment: Best place to ask that is [openoffice forum](http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewforum.php?f=20).

Comment: Maybe that's a good, but for every question on this forum, there is a more specific forum too. Should all move to these more specific forums?

Comment: Well if You search for a quick and best possible answer -- You could post it in both places. Also I doubt that for *every* question there's a specific forum. If You'll get answer at openoffice forum -- You can post here -- so I think it isn't a crime to ask several communtities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Adobe's suggestion, I went to the openoffice forum.

Here is an acceptable answer from there:

Intercept Right Click and cause it to run your Python scrpt, which should be treated as any other macro.

Information on the OpenOffice Python/Uno bridge is at
http://www.openoffice.org/udk/python/python-bridge.html

some further discussion at
http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=12643

Edit: A similar problem is under discussion here
http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=63716